# How to get started with Castle-Windsor?

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

I am completely new with IoC/windsor. I started with Google to learn it, but unfortunately, I haven't got proper documentation which could be easier for me to understand. so I came here with such this title/questions.

Every document/pages(web), Starting something similar like this

> "We  should start from registering the class/interface then resolve it
>   ... "

but none of the page shows complete documentation on how to achieve that, 
I tried to make a simple project too, but I failed to run it. I don't know how to resolve container , where/how to call for install(), I am totally messed up.

Could anyone help me with a sample project which includes a complete demonstration of  registration/installation?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Also [Mark Seemann's Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.amazon.ca/Dependency-Injection-NET-Mark-Seemann/dp/1935182501) book is a good place to start. Well written and has a chapter on Castle Windsor specifically.

They also have some [good tutorials on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9055/Castle-s-DynamicProxy-for-NET), I used before:

**UPDATE**

Well, the most simplistic tutorial would be as follows:

1) In VS2010 create new console application

2) Right click on "References", select "Manage NuGet Packages", install Castle.Windsor

3) Use code below for Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace ExploringCastleWindsor
{
    internal class Program
    {
        interface ILogger
        {
            void Log(string message);
        }

        class Logger : ILogger
        {
            public void Log(string message)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Registering
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.Register(Component.For<ILogger>().ImplementedBy<Logger>());
            // Resolving
            var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
            logger.Log("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the book,
i went through those tutorials but unfortunately unable to integrate these all concepts at a time. plz provide me a simple complete project :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps me a lot :), but i got some issues when i make some changes in it, please check the this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669756/console-writeline-is-not-working-after-resolve

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a tutorial, check this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/543810/Dependency-Injection-and-Unit-Of-Work-using-Castle)

It is explaining CastleWindsor, Nhibernate and UnitOfWork in one example.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add Castle Windsor using

Tools --> NuGet Package Manager --> Package Manager Console.

And than just type **Install-Package Castle.Windsor**

After you done with assamblies you are good to go with code. **Sebastian K** provided a good example of working code.